# How to hide/remove a class based on Bootstrap media query breakpoints?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

Is it possible to show/hide a class based on the screen size of the device?
I am using bootstrap default media query. I have this default setup:

```
/* Bootstrap Media Query Breakpoints

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {...}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones equivalent to class xs */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {...}

/* Small Devices, Tablets equivalent to class sm */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {...}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops equivalent to class md */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {...}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens equivalent to class lg */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {...}
```

I have a div that like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 ol-sm-6 col-md-6">

  <div class="pull-right">

    <ul class="header_links">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Member</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Member Registration</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Help</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Cart: 0</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="social_media_links">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-tumblr-square"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>

</div>
```

What I want is if the media query is in the **col-xs-#** the class **pull-right** will be hidden or removed.
Is it possible in bootstrap?

Comment: The best way to understand Bootstrap is to open the unminified css. In the case of .pull-left, .pull-right, and all of the utility classes (except the responsive utilities) they are for all viewport sizes. If you combine .pull-right AND hidden-xs on the same element <p class="pull-right hidden-xs" then it will hide at the max-width 767px

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bootstrap has built-in utility classes for hiding\showing content based on the viewport.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

`.visible-xs-*` and `.hidden-xs` (* = block, inline-block or inline)

---

EDIT

You won't be able to override `.pull-right` because it uses `!important`, and it only applies one rule (`float: right;`), so its pretty easy to recreate as a custom class.

```
.pull-right-custom {
    float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    .pull-right-custom {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Edit #2

If you want to keep with the mobile-first nature of bootstrap, it would look like this.. the `sm` would indicate it pulls right on `sm` or larger viewports (for semantics).

```
.pull-right-sm {
    float: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
    .pull-right-sm {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the division content. But I want to access a classname using breakpoints

Comment: Those utilities only control the visibility of the element - they are unable to add or remove the "pull-right" class from the inner div as the original post is requesting. You need to use a custom media query as outlined in another answer here or use javascript/jquery to manage it, but the media query approach is easier.

Comment: @Jerielle my most recent update is a slightly better (mobile-first and a little more semantic) so I would use that one.

Answer (score 1):

Hide or remove is not possible, but you can change the way will be rendered

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
  .pull-right {
     float:none;
  }
}
```

So, in this way, in all media screen less then 480px, this class will not be rendered with float:right.

Comment: `visible-xs` is a far better solution as it is provided by bootstrap itself. However, your answer seems to be a unique solution.

Comment: the `.pull-right` class had `!important` applied to it, so you will not be able to override it.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I am thinking now. So the only way I can remove the class is to alter it's main CSS depending on what breakpoint I need it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to do this is to use Bootstrap's [responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).

Take a look at the [source code of visibility mixins definition](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive-utilities.less) as a reference, you can use them to extend your own classes, like:

```css
/* make sure that you've imported Bootstrap */
@import "bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";

.pull-right-custom {
  .pull-right; /* to make element behave exactly like .pull-right; */
  .visible-xs-block; /* to make element visible only on extra-small screens, etc... */
}
```

Or if you're using precompiled or some CDN-shared version of Bootstrap, just add this classes directly into your html like this:

```html
<div class="pull-right visible-xs-block">
  ...
</div>
```